# Accessing different Bing Map Layers

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, bing-maps

Is there a part of the api for access different map layer data such as population heat maps, county boundaries or zipcode lines?

I know this is mostly handled by people like ESRI/ArcServer but I was curious is there was some way to get similar information on the phone platform.

At this point, the only way i see it, is to have a huge data set, parse it, and draw the polygons myself. This sounds extremely time consuming on a phone.

Comment: Dear spammers.  I am not the person who asked the question.  Also, no thanks.  Spammers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly Google, Bing Maps et al. don't expose access to their datasets in anything other than the pre-defined road, satellite styles etc. As tghamm suggests, your best bet for a performant solution on a mobile device is not to draw dynamic polygons, but pre-render your own raster tilesets for the area/zoom levels at which you want to display the data and display these as a custom tile layer ontop of the map control.

A good toolchain for creating such a tileset is:

1.) Use SQL Server Express (or PostGIS, if you prefer) as backend spatial DB - http://www.microsoft.com/express/sql/ ($0)

2.) Get necessary data in shapefile format - http://www.diva-gis.org/Data ($0)

3.) Load the shapefile data into SQL Server - http://www.sharpgis.net/page/shape2sql.aspx ($0)

4.) Write a query to retrieve the necessary information from SQL Server (or retrieve it directly from shapefile) and render it to tiles using Mapnik - http://www.mapnik.org ($0)

Total cost, $0.

Also, be sure to check out open street map - http://osm.org, which provide access to their entire database that you can download and render yourself - in many areas of the world (although not all) it beats both Google and Microsoft in quality and completeness of its data.

Comment: I was hoping for a simple solution for the Windows Phone, but it looks like I need to work something out on Azure. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Often this data is delivered through use of a tile server, where the geometries are rendered on a server and then cut into tiles so that the client is only responsible for consuming the raster data.  There's plenty of places to get good imagery:

http://www.census.gov/geo/www/tiger/
This is a good starting point for your basic geo-political shapes in the US.

From there, there are third party libraries capable of assisting you with consumption of those SHP files directly, such as http://www.thinkgeo.com/.

Alternatively, some people choose to upload the contents of the shp file into a db structure that supports spatial types.  I've used Sql Server 2008, which is complimented by some .Net libraries to facilitate shape handling and manipulation for rendering.

Finally, there are likely a good number of open tile servers out there with useful data layers that you need only understand the tiling pattern to consume, e.g. WMS.

Comment: I will be looking at the open ones. Thinkgeo is looking for around $10K-20K for production/development licenses for WP7. I was thinking more along the lines of $0 :) This is for a very small personal project so I'm willing to get creative.